# Prove by algorithm that a circle cut by $n$ chords can be filled by $2$ colors in a way that adjacent regions differ in color

Tags: proof-writing, algorithms

Example of a circle with the regions colored
[image]

I already proved the theorem using a different technique, but coming from a programmer background I realised that the regions can be colored by following an algorithm, so now I want to try proving by using an algorithm. In a "proof-by-algorithm", how do I prove that the algorithm is correct?

Algorithm:

```
1. Let X be an arbitrary region formed by the chords
2. For every adjacent region Y of X:     
        if Y is not colored:    
           color Y with opposite color of X   
           let X=Y    
           goto step 2
```

Would it now be valid to do a proof by induction, where I assume the algorithm works for $n$ chords, and then proving it works for $n+1$ chords? (and base case)

But like, how do I prove that the algorithm works for $n+1$ chords?

**TLDR:** I have experience coding algorithms, and I also have experience writing math proofs, but this is my first time combining the two, and writing a proof using an algorithm

EDIT: Would it be better to use induction on the amount of regions there are?

Comment: Just to be clear; I guess you don't consider two regions adjacent if they only meet in a single point?

Comment: yes, adjacent region means that they share an edge

Comment: Upon first inspection, I feel like induction should work well. I haven't read the algorithm, but I imagine that you can make the induction hypothesis that "if given k chords, we can do the desired coloring." Now consider drawing another chord. You might have to do some additional casework on whether the new chord intersects multiple other chords at the same point, but that shouldn't be too hard I think

Comment: It makes more sense to induct on the number of chords; take a $2$-coloring of the regions of a circle divided by $n$ chords. Add a chord, and flip all colors on one side of the chord.

Comment: @Servaes yes, that's exactly what I did when proving it at first. But my question was more about how to prove the theorem by using an algorithm. In particular, how do i prove by induction that an algorithm is true

Comment: Find a loop **invariant** which is preserved "all the way long". See for example [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.07223.pdf).